# Determinant $9 \times 9$

Tags: determinant

I am trying to calculate the determinant of the following matrix.

[image]

I literally have no idea if there's a general approach for solving such strange looking determinants, but I decided to subtract the first row from each row after the second. I don't know what to do next...
May you show me what we're supposed to do and how do we find the determinant? Thanks!

Comment: **Note**: An especially efficient method to determine the value of a determinant of order $n$ can be obtained if we transform it in the same way we do in order to determine the rank of a matrix, i.e., all the elements under the diagonal $a_{11}$, $a_{22}$, ... $a_{nn}$ are equal to zero. Then the value of the determinant is the product of the diagonal elements of the transformed determinant.

Comment: det({{-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,8},{-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,16,-9/2},{-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,24,-9,-9/3},{-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,32,-9,-9,-9/4},{-9,-9,-9,-9,40,-9,-9,-9,-9/5},{-9,-9,-9,48,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9/6},{-9,-9,56,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9/7},{-9,64,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9/8},{72,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9/9}})=307211172602709.3

Comment: @MathAttack, I literally don't understand what you've written. May you add an answer and explain how do we solve it? Thank you!

Comment: I wrote you the matrix in full and at the end the result (it wasn't meant to be an answer but just a kindness in case you necessarily needed the numerical result). $$\begin{vmatrix}
-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&8\\-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&16&-9/2\\-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&24&-9&-9/3\\-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&32&-9&-9&-9/4\\-9&-9&-9&-9&40&-9&-9&-9&-9/5\\-9&-9&-9&48&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9/6\\-9&-9&56&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9/7\\-9&64&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9/8\\72&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9&-9/9\end{vmatrix}=-\frac{10752391041094828}{35}$$

Comment: Is it the determinant of a product of 2 matrices?

Comment: Bump………………………..